# What is the best way / approach to printing this specific triangle pattern in C?

Tags: c, printf

The goal is to print this when calling `printTriangle(7);`:

```
      +
     ++
    +-+
   +--+
  +---+
 +----+
+++++++
```

Here is my method so far:

```
int printTriangle(int height)
{
    int x, i, j, space;
    space = height-1;
    for(x=0; x<=height; x++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=space; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        space--;
        for(i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            printf("+");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prints this:

```
      +
     ++
    +++
   ++++
  +++++
 ++++++
+++++++
```

I can't seem to find a way to get the conditionals right for the inner triangle of "-"s, anyone can lead me in the right direction?

Comment: My first idea: recurse ... https://ideone.com/9S9WjB

Comment: Note: It would be nice to declare the function as `void` since it's just printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> anyone can lead me in the right direction?

First we need indexing system. You already have indexing - `x` and `i` are loop iterators, `x` indexes lines from `1` to `height`, `i` indexes `+`/`-` character from `0` to `x - 1` within each line.

```
x|                for(x=0; x<=height; x++)
0|
1|         +
2|        ++
3|       +-+       
4|      +--+
5|     +---+
6|    +----+
7v   +++++++
i----0123456-->   for(i=0; i<x; i++)
```

So first try to formulate conditions with words, then translate them into indexing. For example, we should print `+`:

- on first two lines - `x < 2`
- on the last line - `x == height`
- on the first character in line - `i == 0`
- on the last character in line - `i == (x - 1)`

In all other places we should print `-`. You can try like "we should print `-`, when ...", maybe it will be easier to imagine for you. Then it's finding proper `&&` and `||` between conditions. All together:

```
    for(i=0; i<x; i++) {
        if (x < 2 || x == height || i == 0 || i == (x - 1))
            printf("+");
        else
            printf("-");
    }
    printf("\n");
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the second For Loop:

```
if(i==0||i==x-1)
  printf("+");
else
  printf("-");
```

You can check it [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SkOYeP0Vd)

Answer (score 1):

You will always need to print at least one +, so you can take the first one out of the loop and print it unconditionally. After this, you would like to print a + on the first and last iteration of the loop. The first iteration will be i=0. Since the loop iterates until i<x, on the last iteration of the loop, i will equal x-1. We can check for this in the conditional:

```
int printTriangleFor(int height)
{
    int x, i, j, space;
    space = height-1;
    for(x=0; x<=height; x++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<=space; j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        space--;
        
        for(i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            if ((i==0) || (i == x-1)) {
                printf("+");
            } else {
                printf("-");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, note that your program prints an empty line of spaces on the first iteration through the outer loop. Not sure if this is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int i, j, h=7;
for(i=1; i<=h; i++){
    for(j=i; j<h; j++){
        printf(" ");
    }
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++){
        if(i==h || j==1 || j==i){
            printf("+");
        }
        else{
            printf("-");
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you my solution which is close to best for [code golfing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/):

```c
x,i,j;void f(int h){for(x=0;x<=h;x++){for(j=i;j<h;j++)printf(" "); \
for(i=0;i<x;i++)printf("%c",45-2*(!i||i==x-1||x==h));printf("\n");}}

int main(void) {
    f(8);
}
```

*NB: I hope you don't mind the lack of readability*